Improve Adblock performance by viewing recently blocks
I use adblock. Somesites will bounce through a few servers to see if I'm logged in and do some prep. Sadly it is very hard to 'allow' the sites. IE I go to a site, there is a green hand (allowed domain) I click login and it flashes a red hand and then a green hand and asks me to login. I want to see what the intermediate hosts where so I can allow-list them to.

You have to watch the address bar or view the site's code. There's no universal list of redirects. Also, the only adblocking browser plugin you should use is uBlock Origin. It is the most reputable, most actively developed, and fully featured plugin and it has been for some time.

@music2myear that doesn't work as the browser bounces from server to server a few times very quickly.

The uBlock Origin plugin has a logger.
